# Room | Many to Many relation additional fields

Tags: java, android, database, many-to-many, android-room

I am working on a nutrition tracking app. For that I am trying to setup a many to many relation with some additional fields using Room library. I am not sure yet if its even possible?

The use case I am having trouble with is that I want to retrieve a list of Meals(Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner) along with the foods the user has had along with the portion sizes. 
So it will be something like -> Meals would have a List of Item. Item would have (1)Food + (2)portionSize of that food. The classes are as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Meal {
    @PrimaryKey( autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "MEAL_ID")
    private Long mealId;
}

@Entity
public class Food {
    @PrimaryKey( autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "FOOD_ID")
    private Long id;
}

//Join Table
@Entity(tableName = "MEAL_FOOD", primaryKeys = {"MEAL_ID", "FOOD_ID"})
public class MealFood {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "MEAL_ID")
    private Long mealId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "FOOD_ID")
    private Long foodId;

    private Double portionSize;     
}
```

Now for accessing the data, I am trying something like the following pojo:

```
public class MealWithFoods {
    @Embedded
    public Meal meal;

    @Relation(parentColumn = "MEAL_ID", entityColumn = "FOOD_ID", entity = Food.class, associateBy = @Junction(MealFood.class))
    public List<Item> items;
}

public class Item {
    @Embedded
    private Food food;

    @Relation(parentColumn = "FOOD_ID", entityColumn = "FOOD_ID", projection = {"PORTION_SIZE"}, entity = MealFood.class)
    private Double portionSize;
}
```

DAO:

```
    public interface MealsWithFoodsDao {
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM MEAL")
    public List<MealWithFoods> getMealsWithFoods();
}
```

I have been trying at it for sometime now. Can someone pls offer a path forward. Thanks.